# Non parametric test for regression slope>0?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, bernoulli-distribution

I have some data for a bernoulli variable $Y$ which I believe is a function of time $X$. I have plotted the data below, the slope is negative but I want to test the null hypothesis that the slope is greater than 0.

I know how to perform this hypothesis test for an ordinary regression model by using a t-test but I think that this Bernoulli data greatly violates the assumptions of the t test. Therefore I'm searching for a non-parametric slope test. Of course a test that is specifically for bernoulli regressors would be better but I'm willing to use a non-parametric test

[image: Bernoulli data plot]

Comment: Are you looking for logistic regression?

Comment: @mdewey Actually I wanted to do linear regression. I have to explain it to somebody who doesn't understand mathematics so i wanted to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: I don't understand how you'd perform this test parametrically as a t-test. How do you define the null-distribution when your null hypothesis is that the slope, b1, is > 0? The usual would be the null hypothesis that b1=0.

Comment: @transmetro it's a one tailed test just like the t test for $\mu>0$

Comment: Wait, isn't that $H_a$: $\beta_1$ > 0 as opposed to $H_0$?

Comment: @transmetro $H_0$ is $\beta_1 >0$ and $H_a$ is $\beta_1 \leq0$ It's all essentially a one tailed test for $\beta_1=0$

Comment: OK I'm following now. I think I've only seen the null stated as an equality, but I can see the parallel now that you spell it out. Sorry about filling your comments with this nonsense. So how about a permutation test counting the n.o. times the slope is larger than your estimate under permutation of Y?

Comment: @transmetro Thanks man, that's a clever way to do it. I hadn't thought of using bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a parametric test, but non-parametrically you could always do permutation- or bootstrap tests. I would avoid permutation in this case because there are actually only 9 choose 4 = 126 possible permutations as the response is only ones and zeroes.

If you can make a confidence interval you can do a test, as they are two sides of the same thing. You simply reject if the $H_0$ value falls outside the $(1-\alpha)$-interval. If you want a p-value, find the smallest $\alpha$ for which the $H_0$ value falls outside.

Bootstrapping is a nice non-parametric way to build confidence intervals for your parameters. There are many ways to build bootstrap confidence intervals of varying intricacy. I'll use my favourite, the very straight-forward quantile interval: use the empirical quantiles of the bootstrap distribution over your parameter.

Below is R-code with results for such a test. NB that although you called $X$ time, I have assumed that it doesn't have time series properties. If that were the case, you'd probably have to do block bootstrapping, which adds another layer of complexity.

```r
library(plyr)

# set up data
x <- 1:9
y <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
dataset <- data.frame(x,y)

B <- 50000 # probably overkill
bootstrapped <- raply(B, function() {
  dataset_bootstrap <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), replace=T),]
  coef(lm(y~x, data=dataset_bootstrap))["x"]
})

hist(bootstrapped, col="grey", border="grey", nclass=60)
abline(v=0, col="red")
```

[image]

```r
# your p-value
mean(bootstrapped > 0)
#> [1] 0.0922
```

I'd say there is weak evidence that $\beta_1 \leq 0$

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation, bootstrap looks like the most straightforward way to do this